# Which linux distribution is best for multimedia and gaming?

Tags: linux, games, multimedia

I am looking for a Linux distribution which has good multimedia and gaming support for my laptop.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest [Kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org). According to a benchmark I've seen (can't find it anymore) it has the best FPS in games because of the turn off desktop effects when using fullscreen applications feature (You need to turn it on first however), and the proprietary drivers are very easy to install using the Software Sources (13.04) or Additional Drivers (12.04) program.

Answer (score 0):

While a [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu) like distribution probably provides the best support for your hardware, you should be careful with the desktop manager.

Hence you should prefer

- Xubuntu
- Lubuntu

over [kubuntu](/questions/tagged/kubuntu), because [xfce](/questions/tagged/xfce) and [lxde](/questions/tagged/lxde) are generally more lightweight than [kde](/questions/tagged/kde). You could also try the currently very popular and also on ubuntu basing linux mint with the cinnamon or mate desktop.

Comment: Actually, in my experience the best distro for laptop hardware (by far) is Mint, not Ubuntu.

Comment: Kubuntu has higher performance in full screen apps when having the turn off desktop effects when using fullscreen applications feature on, according to a benchmark I can't find anymore.